# Deploy a web application, ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

***Hello and thank you for your time to read this question!***

I am trying to deploy to GitHub pages, and currently I am using Node and WebPack.

I do not know why it says:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

When I try to navigate to the page that I have just deployed.

The line being affected is:

```
import setCamera from './camera';
```

I have read that require() is not an implemented function in client browsers:
[Client on node: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined/19059825)

So then I have tried to bundle and minify the JS files, however something I can not explain happens.
The pages where I have only one js are correctly minified and the file is called: `fileName.js` and spaces are deleted and variables are uglified.

However in the page I am doing which I have separated into different js files, those are being bundled with requires such as:

```
var _cameras = require('base/cameras/cameras.orthographic');
```

Is there any way to be able to write different JS files and deploy it in a way that the browser could read it,I mean without using require?

The reason why I am confused is because in local with the Node server it works well, however in the remote GitHub pages it does not.

Image which shows the error. When I go to the page's section where is the example that I have refactored usign different js files, loading them via import/export syntax.
[image]

Here I show you how the single js file example provided by the source repo, called viewers_quadview is well minified, however the example refactored with different js files uses require:
[image]

Example given in a single js:
[image]

The example refactored is not being well minified, and imports/exports are replaced by requires:
[image]

Thank you for reading me!